# Equator Hole To The Centre Of A Sphere

Tags: mesh

Could someone please show me jow can i make a hole to the middle of the sphere on the equator?[image]

Comment: Hello :). Similar to the tunnel you already have, but intersecting horizontally?

Comment: The question's a bit unclear can you elaborate a bit?    Do you want something like this:https://pasteall.org/pic/786f8e80b84949f8a65524c9f51038de   OR something like this:  https://pasteall.org/pic/6ed9366da55f4a009b2101ef7960d044  ??

Comment: @JachymMichal Yeah, but not a circle. c:

Comment: @MaulikSharma Here are the images! https://ibb.co/LNLrs65 https://ibb.co/8XMrwHR

Comment: Something like this?? https://pasteall.org/pic/fd0719b26b4a47b48b8798d93425946c

Comment: @MaulikSharma I'm sorry for being unclear, Just a hole around the equator that is square. Like "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgQrm.jpg" That but it goes through the Sphere.

Comment: @MaulikSharma Like that but it doesn't push it all into the hole in the middle. https://ibb.co/Y2Jd2CK

Comment: Got you. Writing the answer

Comment: Thanks @MaulikSharma, sorry for being so unclear.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it,

1. Create a Sphere
2. Select the Center Edge loop[image]
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the edge
   [image]
4. Go to *Face -> Extrude along normals*
   [image]
5. Extrude the faces inside to create the desired effect

Result:

[image]